# Display when next day open is from database results ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, datetime, foreach

I have a SQL table which lists the days of the week and using ASP.Net C# I currently do checks using the current DayOfTheWeek to see if the current day is open or not if the values match the correct active flags also.

[image: Table example]

Columns names for example:

- ID: Incremented ID
- DayOfTheWeek: To hold the day names of the week
- DayOpen: bit flag
- Reminders: bit flag
- TaskDealtWith: bit flag

What I would like to do is expand on this slightly, so that say for example it is Monday but it isn't open until Tuesday, it could display the next day of the week it is open and how many days, for example, 'Next open in 1 day on Tuesday'.

Or if it was Wednesday, 'Next open in 2 days on Wednesday'

But I'm stuck how best to loop through the days and stopping on the next correct value and displaying the results I want?

Any help greatly appreaciated.

Comment: What are the names of the columns? Are they relevant?

Comment: Updated my original post if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question you have one flag, which indicates if open or closed. So you can use a struct to picture this. For example `OpenDay`

In my example the days Tuesday, Wednesday and Saturday are closed. I'm using [fluent assertions](http://www.fluentassertions.com/) to assert the result.

```
[TestFixture]
public class OpenDaysTest
{
    private readonly OpenDay[] _openDays = new[]
                                               {
                                                   new OpenDay { DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday, IsOpen = true }, 
                                                   new OpenDay { DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday, IsOpen = true },
                                                   new OpenDay { DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Tuesday, IsOpen = false },
                                                   new OpenDay { DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Wednesday, IsOpen = false },
                                                   new OpenDay { DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Thursday, IsOpen = true },
                                                   new OpenDay { DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Friday, IsOpen = true },
                                                   new OpenDay { DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday, IsOpen = false }
                                               };

    public string GetNextOpenDayText(DayOfWeek today)
    {
        if (_openDays.All(od => !od.IsOpen))
            throw new Exception("All days are closed");

        var diffDays = 0;
        var index = today;
        DayOfWeek openDay;
        while (true)
        {
            if (_openDays[(int)index].IsOpen)
            {
                openDay = index;
                break;
            }

            diffDays++;
            index++;

            if (index > DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                index = DayOfWeek.Sunday;
        }

        return string.Format("Next open in {0} day{1} on {2}", diffDays, diffDays > 1 ? "s" : string.Empty, openDay);
    }

    [TestCase(DayOfWeek.Monday, "Next open in 0 day on Monday")]
    [TestCase(DayOfWeek.Tuesday, "Next open in 2 days on Thursday")]
    [TestCase(DayOfWeek.Wednesday, "Next open in 1 day on Thursday")]
    [TestCase(DayOfWeek.Thursday, "Next open in 0 day on Thursday")]
    [TestCase(DayOfWeek.Friday, "Next open in 0 day on Friday")]
    [TestCase(DayOfWeek.Saturday, "Next open in 1 day on Sunday")]
    [TestCase(DayOfWeek.Sunday, "Next open in 0 day on Sunday")]
    public void it_should_do(DayOfWeek today, string expected)
    {
        GetNextOpenDayText(today).Should().Be(expected);
    }
}

internal struct OpenDay
{
    public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek;

    public bool IsOpen;
}
```

I have also added a test, if all days are closed.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var ct=0;
var firstOpenDay=dataContext.Days
                 .Where(d=>d.Id>today)
                 .SkipWhile(d=>{ct++; d.IsOpen=='False'})
                 .FirstOrDefault();
var message=$"Next open in {ct} days on {firstOpenDay.Name}"
```

I am assuming that you have today's Id or you are just using DayOfWeek as an id for the Days table.

Comment: I think this code will fail in case the last day of the week is closed?

Comment: True, firstOpenDay will be null in that case and it should be handled.

Comment: I'm using DayOfWeek as the look up at the minute, this is where I'm having one of the problems. So my query will check to see if 'Monday' and True in one of the columns passes.

Comment: I'm also struggling to get this line to work 

.SkipWhile(d=>{ct++; d.IsOpen=='False'})

Either getting 'too many characters in character literal' or wrong statment types.